# give drop-down list if condition not matched

Tags: excel

wanting to use an IF statement (or whatever will do the job) to populate a cell (cell B) based on what was entered in another cell (Cell A), but if Cell A doesn't = x, then I want users to be able to select an answer from a drop-down list

e.g. =IF(B23="Softphone", "Yes", *drop-down list*)

So if Cell A = Softphone, then Cell B is auto-populated with 'Yes'. If Cell A = anything else, then Cell B becomes a drop-down list

Is this possible?

Comment: Personally can't find a way to do it without VBA. Migh be there is, otherwise you'd have to create and delete the dropdown in a `Worksheet_Change` event, with `Range.Validation.Add` and `Range.Validation.Delete`

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I don't think you can do that with IF statements i.e. returning a drop-list if the False condition is returned in your IF statement.

However, you can work around this with a slightly different layout on your worksheet. Try this formula:

**=IF(B23="Softphone", "Yes",IF(D23="","Select option in column D",D23))**

In column D (using the Excel ribbon, select Data and then Data Validation), create a drop-down list of what you want if it's not "Softphone" in column B.

Then, if the input in column B isn't "Softphone", it'll ask the user to select an option from the drop-down list in column D. And if it's blank - it'll show show as a default of 'Select option in column D' like a prompt to the user.